# setInterval slow down on each second during display server time

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, setinterval

After getting date and time server, I am going to update time incrementing by **1 second** on server date and time.
**Problem:**
After display it is going to slow down in browser. I think it takes `1004 ms` 
to increment `1 second`. It seems fine in `Chrome` but slow down in `IE8`.
**My Approach:**

```
var serverdate = null;
var elapsedSecond = null;
var startTime = "<%= getServerStartTime()%>";
window.onload=function(){
     setServerDateAndTime();
 };
 function setServerDateAndTime() {
 var currenttime= 'July 06, 2013 13:10:20';
 serverdate = new Date(currenttime);

 elapsedSecond = callAjax(startTime); //It Gets actual Elapsed Second
 serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds() + parseInt(elapsedSecond, 10));
 setInterval(displaytime, 1000); 
 }

 function displaytime(){
    serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1);
    var timestring = serverdate.getHours()+":"+serverdate.getMinutes()+":"+serverdate.getSeconds();
    var date = serverdate.getFullYear() + ""+(serverdate.getMonth() + 1) +""+ serverdate.getDate();
    document.getElementById("serverDateTime").innerHTML = date +"  " + timestring;
}
function callAjax(value1) {
    var result="";
    var dataObj = {serverStartTime : value1};
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/utility/frameredirect/elapsedTime.action',
        dataType : 'text',
        data : dataObj,
        cache : false, // guarantees jsp is always called
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        }
   });
    return result;
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting a user staying at your page for half an hour, and then get stressed when a clock on the page shows 7 secs wrong ; )? Anyway, timers are not guaranteed to execute tasks exactly in a given time, rather the delay is at least as long as the given amount.

Comment: The Problem is slow down...If the site is an idle state then time will not correct...

Comment: I'm afraid there's no medicin for this. You could try to split the difference (`setInterval(displaytime, 998)`). Or read new "server time" after every 10 minutes. You can also use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`. Please visit [this blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) to read more about timers.

Comment: @Teemu..Okey thanks for the link and information...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is happening because you are finding out the difference in terms of seconds but the setInterval is getting set based on the milliseconds. Hence when it starts to run, even milliseconds cont and adds up to seconds difference.

Hence, in the code:

```
function setServerDateAndTime() {
    var currenttime= 'July 06, 2013 13:10:20';
    serverdate = new Date(currenttime);
    elapsedSecond = callAjax(); //It Gets actual Elapsed Second
    serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds() + parseInt(elapsedSecond, 10));
    setTimeout(displaytime, (60-parseInt(elapsedSecond, 10))*1000); 
}
```

Assuming, the callAjax() method gives you the actual elapsed second, then subtracting the elapsedSecond with 60 will give you the difference in terms of the seconds. So you can try something like this, 60-parseInt(elapsedSecond, 10)

Also, then in the other method you can make use of the setInterval to repeatedly call the displaytime() method.

```
function displaytime(){
    setTimeout(function () { displaytime(); }, 1000);
    serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1);
    var timestring = serverdate.getHours()+":"+serverdate.getMinutes()+":"+serverdate.getSeconds();
    var date = serverdate.getFullYear() + ""+(serverdate.getMonth() + 1) +""+ serverdate.getDate();

}
```

Comment: else simply make ajax calls every 50 seconds to get latest server time and update it...that's it...cos it's server time

Comment: @AnubhavRanjan Looks better, but probably has the same issue as OP's original code... You need to change the delay according to the time elapsed between calls.

Comment: @Teemu that's what the first function call has to do by getting a difference in the time. I don't have enough data as to what is the callAjax() method returning. Based onthat if you compute and find the difference, then the first setTimeout() will align with the actual difference and the rest 1sec updates will be taken care by the setTimeout() in displaytime() method.

Comment: @SJnawali Actually how it does it? Or is it not using AJAX at all, despite of the name. When using normal asynchronous AJAX call, `elapsedSecond` would be undefined at the next line where it's used after `callAjax()`.

Comment: @SJnawali can you also post the callAjax method. It will be helpful for us.

Comment: @SJnawali based on the method, your elapsedSecond is empty. Since, while ajax call is taking place, your function has already returned the value of the variable result

Comment: @AnubhavRanjan: no I have set async: false, so that it always return some value